# Find and hide div (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, hide, href

```
<a rel="abc" href="#mydiv">link</a>
<div id="mydiv">content</div>
```

If rel="abc", find element with ID that matches href value and hide it.

My try:

```
$('[rel*=abc]').attr("href").hide();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Agreed, this does sound a lot like homework

Comment: I'm using Facebox plugin and I'd like to hide the content divs automatically on load. This isn't homework and I post code when I can, but in this case I have no clue.

Comment: Read the documentation on attribute selectors: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: What's the reasoning behind abusing `rel` like this? Something like `class="hidetarget"` would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( $("a[rel='abc']").attr("href") ).hide();
```

Comment: Nice, neater than what I was just writing. Perhaps put this in a $(document).ready(function(){}) block.

Comment: (Note will fail if your IDs contain `.` or `:`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[rel=abc]').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.target.href.substr(event.href.indexOf('#'))).hide();
});
```

Hides the appropriate element if such a link is clicked.

**edit:** tested

Comment: Might want to add event.preventDefault() into that. Or at least return false.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[rel='abc']").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).attr("href");
  $("div"+val).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('a[rel=abc]').each(function() {
    $(this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#'))).hide();
});`

Some error checking would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[rel=abc]").each(function(i, ele) {
    $(ele.hash).hide();
});
```

or if you want that to happen on click

```
$("a[rel=abc]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.hash).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var identifier = $('a[rel="abc"]').attr('href');
$('#'+identifier').hide();
```

I think this may solve your problem. I didn't test it, though.

Comment: Looks like you got -1 because your selector will be "##mydiv"

Comment: Wasn't sure if that would have been the case or not. Thanks for the tip.